# Is there a canonical modern equivalent for David Attenborough?

Tags: documentary

25 years ago, David Attenborough was the gold standard for nature and wildlife documentaries. I'm tempted to get them out for my kids, but I'm worried they'll seem dated to them.

I'm trying to work out if there is a modern 'canonical standard' who has reached the level of esteem of David Attenborough.

My question is: **Is there a canonical modern equivalent for David Attenborough?**

Comment: The perhaps obvious answer is "David Attenborough."  He's very much alive and still writing and producing specials.

Comment: Fantastic- can you put that as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missed my window!  The answer below gives you a great starting point, so I won't re-cover any of those bases.  Enjoy!  Life in Cold Blood is also extremely good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well Planet Earth (IMO the greatest documentary of all time) was narrated by Attenborough and was only in 2006 not 1990. Also David is still involved in some fantastic documentaries. Africa was only released in 2013 and is fantastic. But in answer to your question I don't think there will ever be anyone as good as him. One cannot match his passion.

Comment: The original is better: [Planet Earth 1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Earth_(1986_series)). Also, Carl Sagan would probably beg to differ on that statement: the original [Cosmos 1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos:_A_Personal_Voyage).